$\frac{(a + b + c)^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ integral with $1 \le a,b,c \le 30$
My friend recently sent me the following problem:

For how many ordered triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c \le 30$ is $\frac{(a + b + c)^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ an integer?

We’ve made a bit of progress. It’s enough that
$$\frac{2(ab + bc + ca)}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$
is an integer. But by the rearrangement inequality (or just AM-GM), $ab + bc + ca \le a^2 + b^2 + c^2$. So either
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = ab + bc + ca,$$
which occurs iff $a = b = c$ (which yields $30$ solutions), or
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2(ab + bc + ca),$$
which seems harder.
Without loss of generality, let $a \le b \le c$, so then we want
$$(b - a)^2 + c^2 = 2c(a + b),$$
or substituting $x = b - a$ and $y = a + b$,
$$x^2 + c^2 = 2cy,$$
where $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. We also need $c \mid x^2$, so size conditions imply $c$ cannot be squarefree. But this still leaves a lot of cases. Is there any “clean” way to solve this problem?

Hint: Vieta root jumping technique. Start with $(0, 1, 1) \rightarrow (1, 1, 4) \rightarrow (1, 4, 9) \rightarrow (4, 9, 25 ) $. Note that we can split off at different parts, like $(1, 4, 9 ) \rightarrow (1, 9, 16 )$. And of course, find all base cases / take multiples of your solutions.

@CalvinLin  what I am seeing is that  all three variables must be squares.

I don’t think this is true—consider the case $(a,b,c) = (2,2,8)$.

I see. My method is for when the triple is coprime, $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$

@WillJagy Yes if primitive. Or, simply say that $ab$ is a perfect square. IE $(2, 2, 8) $ is also a solution, but not all squares. $\quad$ This follows because the discriminant of the quadratic of the Vieta root jumping is $16ab$. Rational solution means discriminant is a perfect square (See nonuser's solution - with Puny's comment. Just refreshed and saw that.)

In fact, the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=2(ab+bc+ca)$ can be solved almost completely algebraically. Indeed, observe that $F(a,b,c)=a^2+b^2+c^2-2ab-2bc-2ca$ can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F(a,b,c)
&=a^2-2(b+c)a+b^2+c^2-2bc=(a-b-c)^2-4bc=
\\
&=(a-b-c-2\sqrt{bc})(a-b-c+2\sqrt{bc})=
\\
&=((\sqrt{a})^2-(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})^2)((\sqrt{a})^2-(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^2)=
\\
&=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus, $F(a,b,c)=0$ iff among the numbers $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{c}$ one is equal to the sum of two others. This and the fact that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers leads to $\{a,b,c\}=\{ks^2,kt^2,k(s+t)^2\}$ for some positive integers $s,t,k$ (as in @Cheese's solution).
Remark. The formula above was somewhat motivated by expressions shwing up in Heron's formula.

Beautiful, thanks!

I will deal with the $a^2+b^2+c^2=2(ab+bc+ca)$ case.
Let $(x,y,z)$ be a primitive Pythagorean triplets. Suppose that $x$ is even.
Then, there exist two relatively prime integer $t$ and $s$, which exactly one of them is even, such that
$$\begin{cases} x &=& 2st \\ y &=& t^2 - s^2 \\ z &=& t^2 +s^2 \end{cases}$$
holds.
Now, For the case $a^2 +b^2 +c^2 =2(ab+bc+ca)$, we have
$$(b-a)^2 + (c-a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2$$
Case 1.

$\exists t, s $ and $g\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ b-a = (2ts) g,\quad c-a-b = (t^2 -s^2)g,\quad a+b = (t^2+s^2)g.$$
By solving the system of equations, we have
$$\begin{cases} a &=& \frac{(t-s)^2}{2}g \\ b &=& \frac{(t+s)^2}{2}g \\ c &=& 2t^2g. \end{cases} $$
in this case, since $t$ and $s$ has different parity, $g$ must be even. so you may divide the case $g=2,4,6,8,10,12,14$ and $0\le t\le \sqrt{\frac{15}{g}}$, respectively.

Case 2.

$\exists t, s $ and $g\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$ b-a = (t^2 -s^2)g,\quad c-a-b = (2ts) g,\quad a+b = (t^2+s^2)g.$$
By solving the system of equations, we have
$$\begin{cases} a &=& s^2g \\ b &=& t^2g \\ c &=& (t+s)^2g. \end{cases} $$
you can similarly divide the case with case 1.

You may find the proper $t,s,g$ to generate the whole solutions.

Technically,  your first statement is untrue.  In particular, there are #tri-les when $z=15$ but not $s,t$ with $15=s^2+t^2.$ This solution generates all primitive Pythagorean tripes when $s,t$ are relatively prime and both odd;

@ThomasAndrews thanks for your comments. I will edit it

Also, $(3,4,5)$ does not have this form of solution, since your formula gives only even $x.$ So  again, not even all primitive solutions.

We only need to solve
$$2(ab + bc + ca) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2.$$
As a quadratic in $c$, the discriminant must be a perfect square. Since the discriminant is $16ab$, we require $ab$ to be a perfect square. Similarly, $bc$ and $ca$ are perfect squares.
Suppose $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$, since if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, $(ka,kb,kc)$ is as well. We claim that at least one of
$$\gcd(a,b) \qquad \gcd(b,c) \qquad \gcd(c,a),$$
one of them is one. Otherwise, WLOG suppose $p(\gcd(a,b)) \ge 2$, $p(\gcd(b,c)) \ge 3$, and $p(\gcd(c,a)) \ge 5$, where $p(n)$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$. Now $c \ge 3^2 \cdot 5^2 > 30$, so this is impossible.
Now WLOG $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, so then $a$ and $b$ are perfect squares, so $c$ is a perfect square. So this gives the solution families $(kx^2,ky^2,kz^2)$, which gives a total of $87$.
Oh yeah you also have $(k,k,k)$ which gives $117$ lmao.

I think $x+y=z$ or $y+z=x$ or $z+x=y$ must be satisfied. Did your solution considered it?

@cheese I don’t think this is true, right? For example, for the case $$(1,4,9)$$, $1 + 4 \neq 9$, $1 + 9 \neq 4$, and $4 + 9 \neq 1$. Am I misunderstanding your question?

I mean, as you formulated your solution as $(a,b,c)=(k x^2, ky^2, kz^2)$, One of $+=$  or $+=$ or $+=$ must be satisified.
for example, $x=2, y=3, z=4, k=1$ gives $(a,b,c)=(4,9,16)$, but $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is a odd number.

Oh, I see. Thanks!

Alternatively, write $a=rx^2$ and $b=sy^2$ and $c=tz^2$ with $r$, $s$ and $t$ squarefree. Because $ab$ is a perfect square you have $r=s$, and similarly $r=t$, and so $(a,b,c)=(rx^2,ry^2,rz^2)$.

Since $$(a+b+c)^2= a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\leq 3(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$ ehave $${(a+b+c)^2\over a^2+b^2+c^2}\le 3$$
So you have to check when is $${(a+b+c)^2\over a^2+b^2+c^2} =k$$ here $k\in
\{1,2,3\}$

If $k=3$ then $a=b=c$ so you have 30 solutions.
If $k=2$ then $2(ab+bc+ca)= a^2+b^2+c^2$. Then we have quadratic equation on say $c$ (or $a$ or $b$): $$c^2 -2c(a+b) +a^2+b^2-2ab =0$$ so for some integer $d$ we have $$d^2 = 4(a+b)^2-4(a^2+b^2-2ab) =16ab$$
So $d^2 = 16ab$ and from here it is not difficult to count all the solutions, you have to choose $a,b$ so that their product is perfect square...
If $k=1$ then $2(ab+bc+ca)=0$ and no solutions.


I don't really see how to count all the solutions.

You have to calculate $c$ by choosing $a,b$ @ThomasAndrews

For each square-free number $m$ from $1$ to $30$ there are, $\lfloor \sqrt{30/m}\rfloor$ numbers of the form $mu^2,$ so counting the pairs gives: $\sum_m\lfloor \sqrt{30/m}\rfloor^2,$ wheee $m$ is over the squarefree numbers. Not pretty, but $m>7$ gives only $1.$
